# Field extension with infinite degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm currently working on the proof of the following statement:

> Let $L$ be a field and $K$ and $F$ be two subfields such that $F\subseteq K\subseteq L$. Then the following holds for the field extensions $L/F, L/K$ and $K/F$:
>
> $$L/F \ \ \text{is infinite iff.} \ \ L/K \ \ \text{is infinite or} \ \ K/F \ \ \text{is infinite}$$

I've managed to prove the implication from left to right, and, from right to left in the case of $K/F$ is infinite.

How do I prove the other case, i.e. that if $L/K$ is infinite then so is $L/F$?

Comment: You can prove it via contraposition, that is, suppose that $L/F$ is finite, and prove that $L/K$ and $K/F$ are finite.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is equivalent to its contrapositive

*if $L/K$ is finite and $K/F$ is finite, then $L/F$ is finite.*

Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$ be a spanning set of $K$ as a vector space over $F$ and $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ a spanning set of $L$ as a vector space over $L$.

Now consider $\{x_iy_j:1\le i\le m,1\le j\le n\}$ and conclude.

Hint: if $z\in L$, then
$$
z=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_jy_j
$$
with $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in K$. Then…

For the converse, you want to prove that if $L/F$ is finite, then both $L/K$ and $K/F$ are finite. If you have a finite spanning set of $L$ as a vector space over $F$, then it is also a spanning set of $L$ as a vector space over $K$; moreover $K$ is a subspace of $L$ (both as vector spaces over $F$).

Comment: But OP said that the implication from left to right is done.

Comment: @azif00 Well, the other part is the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $L/K$ is infinite but $L/F$ is finite.

Then $L$ admits a finite set of generators as a $F$-vector space.
These generarators would be also a set of generators as a $K$-vector space, since any linear combination with coefficients in $F$ is also a linear combination with coefficients in $K$. This contradicts the assumption.

Comment: Yes, this seems to make sense. But what about the linear independence of these generators with respect to $K$? Does one have to take that into consideration as well, or does it suffice to argue (like you did) that $L/K$ is finitely generated?

Comment: @SilverPine: of course if you take a **basis** over the smaller field, its element may not be lineraly independent over the bigger field, but they are still generators (obviously). Thus finitely generated over the smaller field implies finitely generatd over the larger field.